# Selecting dynamically inserted HTML elements to change a simple CSS rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a code that lets me "check" table cells, but the ones I create dynamically, don't apply to this.

```
$("td").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
```

This code works great for static elements, but when I create one element...:

```
$("#boton").click(function(){
    var object = {
        name : $("#nombre").val(),
        dni : $("#dni").val(),
        telefono : $("#telefono").val()
    };

    if(count<5){
        count++;
        $("#tabla").append("<tr><td>"+object.name+"</td><td>"+object.dni+"</td><td>"+object.telefono+"</td>");
    }else{
        $("#boton").hide();
        alert("You added too much elements!");

    }
```

... that element is not selectable. The event doesn't fire for it. How can I change this?

Comment: `$(document).on('click','td',function(){` tried this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to detect clicks on current *and future* instances you need to [delegate the event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to an element that does exist (eg the body):

```
$("body").on("click","td",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change te first line of your function:

```
$("body").on("click","td",function(){
```